# wIdth/height inherit behaviour of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem understanding the inheritance of width and height of divs.

I have the following code snippet:

```
<div id="div1" style="width:50%; height:50%;">
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I output the width and height of the divs, div2 returns the same width as div1, but not the same height. Why is this so? Width and height are not supposed to be inherited so in my oppinion both should show 0px for div2.

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(div1).width); // 727px
console.log(getComputedStyle(div1).height); // 494.5px
console.log(getComputedStyle(div2).width); // 727px
console.log(getComputedStyle(div2).height); // 0px
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for width is that `div`s are `display: block`, automatically. Blocks span the entire width of their parent, unless a `width` css property is specified, in which case they would use that.

As for height, `div`s will try to be as small as possible. Since `#div2` has no content, its height will be 0 pixels. For `#div1`, a `height` property is specified, so it will be 50% the height of its parent, which I assume is your browser window.

Note that the dimensions you specified are not necessarily fixed- they are just the values that are computed for your browser window's size.

Answer (score 1):

Width and height values of a percentage value calculate pixel values relative to their container which is the only reason you're seeing a height on the first/parent div.

The reason you're seeing a width is because divs are block elements which means they span the width of their parent by default.

The default height value of a block element is that of its contents.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are specifying `div1` to have a percentage (50%) of width and height of the container of `div1`, so they have a width and height which are non-zero.

For `div2`, the width in general goes the full width of the container (which is `div1`), unless if you specify otherwise, such as using `width: 30px` or `width: 25%`, etc.  The height is the height of the content of `div2`, which in this case is 0.  (the whitespaces are ignored in this case.  If you want to experiment, add a `&nbsp;` there and you will get a non-zero height).